# Power BI Date Column

Tags: datetime, powerbi

I'm making a gantt chart using Matrix and can't figured out how can I make the date as headers. I want to copy the design like on this picture. [image]

I want to use as header in my matrix gantt chart. So the final design should be like this:[image]
[image]

The blue one is my current design so far :-) I

Comment: Isn't it easier to use [Gantt visual](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA104380765?tab=Overview)?

Comment: @AndreyNikolov, yes Gantt visual is easy to use but the requirement is to use matrix which has a drill through capability.